# Error using DataFrame index of given attribute using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to pull the values in an attribute of a dataframe i made but python is does not recognize the attribute.

### the data frame has 5 cloumns and i can call all of them except the Namesof column

other column:

```
 print(raw.Gender[1])

MALE
```

---

the Namesof column:

```
print(raw.Namesof[1])
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-14-625b108917c2>", line 1, in <module>
    print(raw.Namesof[1])

  File "blank", line 5179, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Namesof'
```

Raw data frame

```
 print(raw)

   Year  Gender Ethnicity            Namesof   Count

  2014    MALE  WHITE NON HISPANIC    Yidel          10
```

[19418 rows x 5 columns]

Comment: Try ```raw["Namesof"]``` or even ```raw.iloc[1, "Names of"]``` to get second row of that column (put 0 instead of 1 to get first row)

Comment: raw["Namesof"]  doesn't work?

Comment: neither worked. keyerror Namesof . even when i type raw. and hit tab the other attributes are there but namesof is the only one not there. I am not sure if the issue lies in the data frame itself. but when i double click it or print the dataframe there is definitely a Namesof column as shown above

Comment: Whats the output of raw.columns? Maybe there is an extra space in the name?

Comment: As above try ```print(raw.columns)```

Comment: Did you try that? `raw.columns = [col.replace(' ', '') for col in raw.columns]` and `print(raw.Namesof[1])`

Comment: print(raw.columns) result: 
Index(['Year', 'Gender', 'Ethnicity', 'Namesof ', 'Count'], dtype='object')

Comment: IDK what the issue was but for some reason when i tried print(raw.Namesof[1]) after raw.columns = [col.replace(' ', '') for col in raw.columns] and print(raw.columns) it worked. as for why it didnt recognize the column before..... i guess it doesnt matter now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there's a space in the column names. You can try this,

```py
raw.columns = [col.replace(' ', '') for col in raw.columns]
print(raw.Namesof[1])
```